# Eigenvalues of a certain block matrix

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I need a way for computing the eigenvalues of the block matrix
\begin{equation}R=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & B \\
        B^T & D  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
where:

- $B$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix.
- $D$ is a an  $n \times n$ matrix
- $0$ is the null $1 \times 1$ matrix

By using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices, it is known that 
$$char(R) = \det(-s(D-sI)-B^TB).$$

How to find the roots of char(R)? Is there a formula in terms of eigenvalues of $D$ and $B^TB$?

For instance, let B=[b1,b1,b1,b2,b2,b2,b2], where b1=1/$\sqrt{21}$ and b2=1/$\sqrt{14}$
 and D be a matrix with rows [[0,r,r,0,0,0,0],[r,0,r,0,0,0,0],[r,r,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,s,0,0],[0,0,0,s,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,s],[0,0,0,0,0,s,0]], where r=1/3 and s=1/2.
Then the following sage code gives the roots as: [1.000, 0.601, 0.500, -0.333, -0.333, -0.435, -0.499, -0.500]. Note that eigenvalues of D: {2/3,-1/3,-1/3,-1/2,-1/2,1/2,1/2}
and $B^TB$: {3/7,0,0,0,0,0,0}.

p=2

b1=1/(sqrt(3*(3+2*p))

b2=1/(sqrt(2*(3+2*p))

B=Matrix(Reals(),[b1,b1,b1,b2,b2,b2,b2])

Id=identity_matrix(Reals(),3+2*p)

r=1/3

s=1/2

D=Matrix(Reals(),[[0,r,r,0,0,0,0],[r,0,r,0,0,0,0],[r,r,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,s,0,0],[0,0,0,s,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,s],[0,0,0,0,0,s,0]])

s = PolynomialRing(CC, 's').gen()

char_R=(-s*(D-s*Id)-(B.transpose())*B).det()

char_R.roots()

---

Use online calculator: http://aleph.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 1):

In general, the characteristic polynomial of $R$ will have degree $n+1$, and may be irreducible.  For a somewhat random example, take
$$ B = (0,1,2,0),\ D = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1 & -1\cr -1 & -1 & 2 & 1\cr -1 & 1 & 2 & 0\cr 2 & 2 & 0 & 2\cr}$$
where $R$ has characteristic polynomial
$$ t^5 - 4 t^4 - 5 t^3 + 19 t^2 - t - 30 $$
This has Galois group $S_5$, according to Maple, and thus is not solvable by radicals.  Therefore the eigenvalues can't be written as expressions (involving the arithmetic operations and radicals) in the eigenvalues of $D$ and $B B^T$ (which are expressible in radicals).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked your example. You are right that there is no eigenvalue of D appears as an eigenvalue of R (pls note that D is not symmetric, so there are some complex eigenvalues.) On the other hand the example that I gave says the opposite: Eigenvalues of D appears as the eigenvalues of R? (except 2/3 and one of 1/2) Do you think that it was just a coincidence? I have also checked some random symmetric matrices they don't have this property either.

Comment: Somewhat more generally, with your $D$ and $B$ (but with arbitrary $b_1, b_2, r, s$),
the characteristic polynomial of $D$ is $(t-2r) (t+r)^2 (t-s)^2 (t+s)^2$ while the characteristic polynomial of $R$ is $$(t+r)^2 (t-s) (t+s)^2({t}^{3}+ \left( -2\,r-s \right) \left({t}^{2}+ \left( -3\,{{ b_1}}^{2}-4\,
{{ b_2}}^{2}+2\,rs \right) t+3\,{{ b_1}}^{2}s+8\,{{ b_2}}^{2}r
\right)$$

Comment: What's happening here is that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $D$ that happens to be orthogonal to $B$, then $\pmatrix{0\cr v\cr}$ is an eigenvector of $R$ for the same eigenvalue.

Comment: That's the crucial point. Orthogonality. Thx. I will be working on this problem and check the reason for the order of eigenvalues and their magnitude. Your comments really help on this road.